# what can be done to make the cards of horizontal scroll responsive?

Tags: html, css

it loses its responsivity in 282px what can be done to make it responsive till 244px at least? Moreover, it does not show one card at a time after 282 px. I want it to automatically adjust to screen width and show one card at a time till 244px (at least). How can it be done? Please guide me to do the same.

```js
let currentScrollPosition = 0;
    let scrollAmount = 320;

    const sCont = document.querySelector(".card-container");
    const hScroll = document.querySelector(".horizontal-scroll");
    const btnScrollLeft = document.getElementById("btn-scroll-left");
    const btnScrollRight = document.getElementById("btn-scroll-right");
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // i prefer adding event listeners in javascript.
    btnScrollLeft.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      scrollHorizontally(1);
    });
    btnScrollRight.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      scrollHorizontally(-1);
    });
});

function scrollHorizontally(val) {
      let c_width = hScroll.offsetWidth,
          box_width = sCont.offsetWidth,
          amount = val * scrollAmount,
          diff = c_width - box_width;
      // to calculate the difference, we only need to subtract width of the div containing the cards.
      currentScrollPosition = currentScrollPosition + amount;

      if (currentScrollPosition > 0) {
        // cap start
        currentScrollPosition = 0;
        btnScrollLeft.style.opacity = "0";
      } else if (currentScrollPosition < diff) {
        // cap end
        currentScrollPosition = diff;
        btnScrollRight.style.opacity = "0";
      } else {
        btnScrollLeft.style.opacity = "1";
        btnScrollRight.style.opacity = "1";
      }
      sCont.style.left = currentScrollPosition + "px";
    }
```

```css
.horizontal-scroll {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .card-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-basis: 30%;
      position: absolute;
      gap: 10px;
      left: 0;
      transition: 1s left ease-out;
      overflow-x:hidden
    }

    .card-container .card {
      min-width: 280px;
      flex: 1;
      height: 200px;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background: #fff;
      background: #00F260;
      /* fallback for old browsers */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #0575E6, #00F260);
      /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0575E6, #00F260);
      /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      text-align: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .card-container .card img {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      pointer-events: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      width: 100%;
      float: none;
      display: block;
      object-fit: fill;
      height: 180px;
    }

    /* btn */

    .horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll {
      background: 0;
      border: 0;
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 0 10px;
      z-index: 10;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: #007bff;
    }

    .horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #007bff;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll:focus {
      outline: none;
      background-color: #007bff;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-left {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: calc(200px/2);
    }

    .horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-right {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: calc(200px/2);
    }
    @media( max-width:  768px){
      .card-container{
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"/>

<div class="horizontal-scroll">
      <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-left" onclick="scrollHorizontally(1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </button>
    
    <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-right" onclick="scrollHorizontally(-1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </button>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">Card 1</div>
        <div class="card">Card 2</div>
        <div class="card">Card 3</div>
        <div class="card">Card 4</div>
        <div class="card">Card 5</div>
        <div class="card">Card 1</div>
        <div class="card">Card 2</div>
        <div class="card">Card 3</div>
        <div class="card">Card 4</div>
        <div class="card">Card 5</div>
      </div>
      <!--card-container-->
    </div>
    <!--horizontal-scroll-->
```

Comment: Why don't you use Swipper.js or OWL.js?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need it, but the smallest usual phone width is 320px which is still good for your case.

Comment: not 320, as a budding developer i want to know it. Moreover , i am learning hard coding ,i.e. everything from scratch. So i want to learn. And also min width for Samsung galaxy z fold and flip is 252px if am not wrong.

Comment: You have set a min width which is wider than the smallest screen width you want to accommodate. Is this intentional?

Comment: yes.... should i decrease the min width? try to reduce the min - width and see.